# software for Braun's 2007 method for simultaneously optimizing dose and schedule of a new cytotoxic agent (in a phase 1 clinical trial)

Tags: library, r

Is there an R library or other implementation for Braun's 2007 Bayesian method for simultaneously optimizing dose and schedule of a new cytotoxic agent (in a phase 1 clinical trial) https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1740774507076934 ?

Comment: The Journal Link is behind a paywall.

Comment: Maybe ask the developer(s) of the ["dfped" R package](https://github.com/artemis-toumazi/dfped) (Dose finding in Pediatrics?) by opening an issue on github. (Don't ask directly for help, instead tag the question as an "enhancement request" or similar)

Comment: thanks for your help, knb, I'll look at that package and suggestion of enhancing it

Answer (score 0):

can't download this at the moment but this may be software that does the Braun method https://biostatistics.mdanderson.org/softwaredownload/SingleSoftware.aspx?Software_Id=75